# Is this C header written properly?

Tags: c++, c, header, shared-libraries, static-libraries

I am learning (trying) how to write my own C/C++ headers, and get functions out of the body of my code. For this I wrote nyanlib.h, and nyan.cpp

Ignoring that its a trivial program, please tell me if the header is written correctly, or if I am making serious mistakes? The code works though.

Here is nyan.cpp:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <unistd.h>
#include "nyanlib.h"

using namespace std;
int main()
{
    while( true )
        {
            print_nyan(); //function from nyanlib
            sleep(1);
        }
return 0;   
}
```

and [Here is nyanlib.h](http://pastebin.com/Bwp6N8rc)

Also, Would nyanlib.h be a shared library or a static library?

Comment: "Also, Would nyanlib.h be a shared library or a static library?" Depends on compiler settings.

Comment: Although that may compile and run, that's not how to do a .h and .cpp file.  As a general rule, the header should contain declarations and the .cpp file should contain implementations.

Comment: It's bad practice to define functions in your header file. Move the definition of `print_nyan()` to your .cpp file, and keep its declaration in the header.

Comment: Also, this is C++, not C.

Comment: Rational for downvote: An external link to the header that's the crux of "Is this C header written properly?" is a poor choice. Once pastebin purges or moves that document, this question is utterly useless.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

What you have as nyanlib.h should be renamed to nyanlib.cpp.  Then nyanlib.h would contain only the following:

```
#ifndef NYANLIB_H
#define NYANLIB_H

void print_nyan();

#endif
```

You can then compile the library as an object file:

```
g++ -c nyanlib.cpp
```

This gives you nyanlib.o.  So now your main file contains just a prototype of `print_nyan()` from the header file so it knows how to call it.

Then you compile the main program:

```
g++ -c nyan.cpp
g++ -o nyan nyan.o nyanlib.o
```

Comment: where does the function go?

Comment: @j0h The definition of the function (which contains the body) goes in nyanlib.cpp.  The declaration (a single line defining the parameters and return type) goes in the nyanlib.h.

Answer (score 1):

Yes and no. While it is a *valid* header, you are using it a bit strangely. Most of the time, a header is used as a way to expose methods and variables related to the class and not to perform functionality.

For your case if you want to make it "better", I would bring the implementation of the print_nyan() function into the cpp file, and just leave a prototype of the function in the header.

And I would say that it is neither a static nor a shared library since it has a main. If you wanted to make it a library, you should make a separate header and source file that defines the print_nyan() function, make that your library, and use that library in your main function.